# Redirect to error page doesn't work with open dialog

Tags: ajax, exception, primefaces, dialog

I click on

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show()" />

 <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1">
   <p:inputText id="dogName" value="#{mngBean.dogName}" />
</p:dialog>
```

an exception is thrown in MngBean in `getDogName()` method.  PrimeExceptionHandler catches it and does redirect to an error page but nothing happend on client side. Redirect doesnt work and no ajax response sent back to client side. 
Exception handler works well in all other cases except when dialog is open.
I can't figure out how to handle exceptions thrown in dialog render phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primefaces has uncovered this case when an exception is thrown during rendering partial response for dialog. In this case partial response writer ends up with malformed XML and dialog hangs up on the screen with invalid content.
The only solution I figured out is to owerride `PrimeExceptionHandler` and its `handleRedirect` method in which I added

```
PartialResponseWriter writer = context.getPartialViewContext().getPartialResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement( "script", null );
        writer.write( "window.location.href = '" + writer.write("window.location.href = '" + context.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + errorPage + "?message=" + info.getMessage() + "';" );
        writer.endElement( "script" );
        writer.getWrapped().endCDATA();
        writer.endElement( "update" );
        writer.getWrapped().endDocument();
```

This way I add script to be executed after malformed dialog shows up which will redirect it to error page.